# ShapefileException when reading shapefile using PyShp

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I'm trying to read in a shapefile and keep getting a File Not Found error and this exception:

> ShapefileException: Unable to open /Users/name/Documents/shapefile.shp

Here's what I've got:

```py
import shapefile

# read the shapefile
reader = shapefile.Reader('/Users/name/Documents/shapefile.shp')
```

I've tried several variations of that and still get the error. The shapefile exists and it works. It's also in the same folder as the *.dbf* and *.shx* files. Any ideas?

Comment: Does "name" have a space in it?

Comment: Yes it does actually. Perhaps replace that with an underscore?

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: There are enough wonky things with the path reference that you should test if `os.path.exists()` can find the file first.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions? Or do you have it open in any other software at the same time as trying to open the file?

Comment: Jeez, thanks for all the input here. I've tried all these things and still no luck. I tried it with a different shapefile and had same issue. I've tried using the r before the string chain and both the \ and / slashes. The path does exist and it works. There is an earlier line of code that I have reading a CSV file and that worked fine. The only thing I'm unsure of is the permissions and if that could have something to do with it, but not sure how to check.

Answer (score 1):

I could also get the [`ShapefileException`](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/blob/master/shapefile.py#L1190) when:

- the path to a shapefile is wrong
- the shapefile's name was wrongly specified
- there is no permission to access the shapefile

First of all, I suggest to double check the path to your shapefile:

- correctness of slashes `/`, backslashes `\`, double backslashes `//` based on the OS

As was mentioned by @Vince test whether the shapefile exists using [`isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) and [`exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) functions from the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) module:

```py
import shapefile
from os.path import isfile, exists

absolute_path_to_file = '/Users/name/Documents/shapefile.shp'

dbf = absolute_path_to_file.replace('.shp', '.dbf')

if isfile(absolute_path_to_file) and exists(dbf):
    shp = shapefile.Reader(absolute_path_to_file)
    print(shp)
```

Another suggestion is to test your shapefile with the [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) package using functions from the [test_shapefile.py](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp/blob/master/test_shapefile.py):

```py
import pytest
import shapefile

absolute_path_to_file = '/Users/name/Documents/shapefile.shp'

with pytest.raises(shapefile.ShapefileException):
    with shapefile.Reader(absolute_path_to_file) as sf:
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this solution? reader = shapefile.Reader(r'/Users/name/Documents/shapefile.shp'). Just add r before the string chain. otherwise try by using the \ instead of /.

Comment: A raw string (`r'some string'`) will have no effect on forward slashes and changing forward slashes to backwards will not work on a non-Windows OS.